# function on every keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run the following block on every keypress of right arrow (39):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var pos = 10;
        if (e.keycode = 39) {
        if (pos > 10) {
        pos + 10;
      }
        $(".mario").css('left', pos);
    }
    });
});
```

The goal is I am setting a variable, `pos`, and referencing it in a `css()` method to move it across the screen in increments of 10, every time the key is pressed the expected behavior is on every right arrow key hit, the object moves across the screen in increments of 10.

It works successfully once, then will not continue to increment. My console is empty/free of errors. I have also tried using `keypress`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var pos = 10;
        if (e.keycode = 39) {
        if (pos > 10) {
        pos + 10;
      }
        $(".mario").css('left', pos);
    }
    });
});
```

To elaborate on this, I also want to add an option to check if the left key is pressed and if so, set it back flush against the screen. I went about this by adding the below block under the closing of the first if statement:

```
else if (e.keycode = 37) {
        $(".mario").css('left', '0');
    }
```

I researched on MDN and it simply states: "The keydown event is fired when a key is pressed down." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown

Reading that, what I'm not understanding is why is my event only firing once? How come adding a second condition for the left arrow key doesn't register as an event, if the event is fired every time a key is pressed?

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c2fr7rsd/1/

EDIT/UPDATE: As many pointed out, I was/am using an assignment operator `=` and not a comparison `===` - I initially tried comparison it doesn't work. Assignment - it works, but now all the keycodes register as 39! Howcome in this instance, the comparison operator doesn't reference the keycode?

UPDATE #2 - using `e.which` is the correct way to handle keydown events, and using the correct comparison `===` works

Comment: use `==` or `===` for comparison, not `=` (which is the assignment operator).

Comment: @TravisJ that's interesting you said that - when I first worked on this, I used `==` but I couldn't get the event to fire. I looked at other SO answers and they all use `==` but mine requires a single `=` to work. I'm not sure why...

Comment: There are a number of errors with your code. Every time the keypress function is run, pos is set to 10. Thus, pos will never be greater than 10, it always gets set to 10. Additionally, `=` is used for assignment, `==` or `===` is used to check equality. Finally `pos + 10` won't do what you expect, you want `pos += 10`. But for that to work, you probably need to get the current left position first instead of just always setting pos to 10.

Comment: You have numerous errors. (1) `pos > 10` will always be false, because (2) you're setting `pos` to 10 every time a key is pressed. Then (3) `pos + 10` wouldn't actually change anything anyway - you probably meant `pos += 10`. And as has been pointed out `e.keycode = 37` will always be true as it will assign `37` to the keycode property, return 37 and evaluate as `true`

Comment: @skyline3000 jinx! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pos variable should be declared as a global.(outside the function).
Right now, each time that function is called, the variable is set back to 10.

Also logic for checking that variable should be

```
if(pos >= 10)
```

And setting the variable should be

```
pos += 10
```

Also capitalize C in keyCode and the == will work
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

This shows why your logic for if(e.keycode = 39) was returning true
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_mistakes.asp

Correct code example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pos = 10;    
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {    
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        if (pos >= 10) {
        pos += 10;
      }
        $(".mario").css('left', pos);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: hard to see what the `if` is for at all tbh

Comment: hummm please dont just say global - rather talk about scope.

Comment: `pos` doesn't have to be global. You simply have to read the left offset of the element, update it, and assign it back. Using global variables quickly pollutes the scope.

Comment: wouldn't checking the css every time be inefficient? @Terry

Comment: So this is the core root of the issue - setting `pos` globally was the key since I was always setting it to 10. However, as many others have noted I'm using assignment `=` and not proper comparison `===` but if I try to do it properly it doesn't work at all. Why would that be?

Comment: try if(e.keyCode == 39)  (captialize the C). before you could have hit any key and the statement would have returned true. Because 39 is equivalent to true.